# Transforming matrix into matrix with orthogonal columns

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that I have $p \times n$ matrix $A$. Is it always possible to multiply it by some orthogonal $p \times p$ matrix $B$ so that columns of $BA$ are orthogonal?

I tried finding the $B$ using SVD decomposition of $A$

$A = U\Sigma V^T$

Multiplying by $U^T$ from the left was my first idea, but I couldnt find anything to make $\Sigma V^T$ into matrix with orthogonal columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $BA=Q$ where $B$ is orthogonal and $Q$ has orthogonal columns. This means that $B^\top B=I$ and $Q^\top Q$ is diagonal. It follows that $A=B^\top Q$. Thus
$$
A^\top A
= (B^\top Q)^\top(B^\top Q)
= Q^\top B^\top B Q
= Q^\top Q
$$
This means that $A^\top A$ is diagonal, which implies that $A$ has orthogonal columns.

So, if $A$ does not have orthogonal columns, then we can't find an orthogonal $B$ such that $BA$ has orthogonal columns.